# Collision, position being reset

Tags: c#, xna, collision

I'm having a bit of a problem with my collision, after finally figuring out how to actually make it collide i could only make the pacman reset into a set position and have no idea how to make him stay where he's supposed to.

```
     player.update();

        for (int y = 0; y < NrOfTilesY; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < NrOfTilesX; x++)
            {

                if (tileArray[x, y] is Nest)
                {
                    Rectangle rectW = tileArray[x, y].Bounds();
                    Rectangle rectP = Player.pacmanBounds;
                    if(rectW.Intersects(rectP))
                    {
                        Player.pacmanBounds.X = 32;
                        Player.pacmanBounds.Y = 32;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you move the player, copy its position.

If it collides after you moved it, re-placed it to the last position.

Also, I think it would be worthy to note that you don't need to test every tiles of your board, but only the tiles around the player. The position of the player should give you on which tile it is, and should be fairly easy to find the tiles adjacent to that tile.

Comment: sorry, I'm really quite new to this, my player is not part of the array, how does one go about checking the position=?

Comment: The player has a position, right? And each tile in the array also have one? In a simplified way, the X and Y of the player can easily be translate in the index in X and Y of your tiles.

Comment: Player.pacmanBounds.X <--- im guessing thats it=? but if i change the value to for ex Player.pacmanBounds.X-1 it collides to the right but if i try going to the left it flies through the walls.

Comment: never mind, i re-read your answer while having lunch and and it hit me, It works, thankyou.